# How Do I SELECT when needing to use LIKE and change column Name

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the problem I am working on:

1. Select all the Oracle database employees whose last names end with “s” Change the 
   heading of the column to read Possible Candidates.

I tried

```
SELECT last_name AS possible_candidates FROM * WHERE last_name LIKE '%s';
```

That returned the error :

```
ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

Unless I am reading the question wrong how do I check the entire database for something like this?

Comment: Is there a table called employees? if that I would interpret the question as from the employees table. Otherwise, you could `select table_name from All_TAB_COLS where column_name like = 'LAST_NAME'` and then build a union from the resulting tables all of which  have a field called 'LAST_NAME'..

Comment: I think you want `FROM employees` not from the entire database.

Comment: That's it I misread the question. The table is employee's thank you.

Comment: Since the title was misleading I edited to better reflect the question. If this is incorrect speak up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on feedback: this appears to be your answer...

Is there a table called employees? if that I would interpret the question as from the employees table. Otherwise, you could select table_name from All_TAB_COLS where column_name like = 'LAST_NAME' and then build a union from the resulting tables all of which have a field called 'LAST_NAME'

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question which is asking for employee names not just last names you would select all employees with a last name that ends in S.

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees
WHERE last_name LIKE '%s'
```

If the table has more than a first_name and last_name column you can do

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM employees
WHERE last_name LIKE '%s'
```

**Now to combine your two parts (Select employees and rename column)**

Run one of the two queries above but add an AS statement as show in the example below.

```
SELECT * 
AS Possible_Candidates
FROM employees
WHERE last_name LIKE '%s'
```